# C++ Hello World freezes on Windows

Tags: c++, mingw, freeze

The last days I began learning C++. As with every language I began making a Hello World program. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "I'm doomed in Windows :(" << endl;
}
```

I compiled it with g++ (from MinGW) like this:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp
g++ -o hello hello.o
```

The output is:

```
hello.exe
```

But when I open hello.exe it freezes / doesn't start. I tried both to open it via the command line as opening it with the GUI. It looks like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByNRkSnhavxIaXh6a2JSaEpZV0k/view?usp=sharing

Does anybody know what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

PS: If you wonder why I didnt post the image inline, I can't. I need 10 reputation points for that ^^.

Comment: We've been having this question asked all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: @Hans I guessed you were to say - uninstall Windows. :-D

Comment: @HansPassant It works deactivating Avast! Thanks! Yes, I saw several posts saying it was Avast, but I couldn't imagine it would be my case as well. It turns out it was. Thanks again Hans! :)

Ps. How can I close this question? Do I have to post an answer myself and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by deactivating Avast, thanks to Hans Passant. It is also possible to add the executable to the Avast exclusion list.